# Is the Go Data Race Detector deterministic?

Tags: go

If the [Go Data Race Detector](https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector) reports a data race in a program, will it always report a data race in that program, no matter how many times it is run?

Comment: There is no guarantee for that. For example if you launch multiple gorotuines that access a shared variable without synchronization, they may or may not get to the point to cause the data race before the main goroutine ends and the whole app is terminated. Data races are only reported when they occur and are detected.

Comment: Of course not. If your program terminates on Wednesday without doing anything it cannot detect any race in code executed on Sundays.

Comment: It is very hard to have determenistic data race detector: to be deterministic, such a tool would have to implement _static_ code anaylzis. Writing such a tool is not impossible but is insanely hard—especially for a language such as Go which sacrifices the property of being easy for computers to reason about for the property of being easy and fun for people to program in. Because of this, Go's race detector is dynamic: it instruments the resulting machine code in a special way to be able to catch data races, but it only catches them _when they actually occur in a given run of a given program…_

Comment: …and each such run is _heavily_ influenced by a number of things like the particular hardware, the current load on the system (and its fluctuations during the program execution) and even the version of the toolchain which built your program (different compilers may produce different machine code).